# Почему конструктор форм ведет себя неадекватно при использовании хука на мышь в c#

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, form, resize

Вообщем создал форму со свойством bs=none и через хук на мышь реализовал её растягивание (масштабирование) или как это правильно назвать. При запуске все отлично работает, но при переходе в конструктор формы начинаются дикие глюки такие как:

1. При любом клике внутри vs мышь курсор телепортируется куда-нибудь в радиусе 150 пикселей при этом меняется размер формы
2. В диспетчере задач можно наблюдать как "Системные прерывания" грузят процессор на 99%
3. В итоге vs зависает и выдает ошибку как на картинке

[image: Ошибка]

Почему это происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: хук на мышь в конструкторе инициируете? Судя по вопросу - да, с чем вас и поздравляю. Дизайнер использует конструктор формы при ее отображении, именно поэтому в нем ничего лишнего быть не должно, ни хуков, ни загрузки данных из посторонних источников, ничего, кроме настройки внешнего вида формы. Все лишнее выносите в событие Load, которое дизайнер не использует и не провоцирует его срабатывание.

Comment: Вас спасёт событие `Form.Load`, перенесите ваш код, который надо выполнить при запуске формы, туда.

Comment: @rdorn большое спасибо, но заметил, что если перенести инициализацию в Load и унаследоваться от такой формы, то конструктор (дизайнер) наследника опять начинает шалить, неужели наследник использует Load суперкласса для своего отображения?

Comment: @volvo это возможно. Тогда можно попробовать прикрыть хук проверкой свойства [DesignMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.designmode?view=netframework-4.8), не у верен что поможет в наследниках, но попробовать стоит.

Comment: @rdorn попробовал проверку DesignMode и это сработало даже для наследника, спасибо.

Comment: можете написать ответ по мотивам нашего обсуждения. Для хорошего ответа перечислите ошибки, которые вы у себя обнаружили и фрагмент кода, который помог их исправить